# Increased retain count when converting to ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I'm converting a library to ARC atm. where I have an NSViewController descendant that loads a xib the usual way:

```
- (instancetype)initWithModule: ...
{
  self = [super initWithNibName: @"mynib" bundle: [NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]]];
  if (self != nil) {
    [self view];
  }

  return self;
}
```

When I executed this without ARC the retain count of that controller is 2 after the call to view (which loads the nib and connects the outlets, as you know). However with ARC enabled this increases the retain count to 3, which later causes this controller to leak, because the count never goes back to 0.

I changed all outlets to use weak references (except for NSTextView instances, but they never appear as top level objects). But this doesn't seem to help.

**Update:** It seems to affect every view controller I have, at least all those I checked. So this seems to be a fundamental problem, not related to the xib content.

How can I find out what causes the additional retain on load?

Comment: To find out, use Instruments.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I tried already to profile allocations, but that list is telling me nothing I could use here.

Comment: Use the Leaks instrument.  While the app is running, find the object which is leaking and click on the little circled arrow next to the memory address (3rd column).  The view will switch to showing you the MM history for the object.  You can see where every retain and release happens.  It's up to you to figure out which retain is the extra one.

Comment: The controller doesn't even appear in the list of leaked objects. Seems to be a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute retain count is meaningless.  You need to find all the spots where `retain` is called (or called by implication, in the case of ARC).

To do that, use the Allocations instrument and turn on reference count tracking.   That'll give you access to the backtrace of every single retain and you can find the extra one.

More likely than not it'll be a strong reference to `self` in a block held by something in `self`.   Or it'll be a cycle of strong references;  `self -> other -> self` kinda thing.

Comment: Tbh, I still have a hard time to even make sense of this part of Instruments. There's way too much noise that keeps me from focusing on what I'm actually interested in. However, staring long enough at the code (maybe including use of the brain ) often helps, so also in my case. All the controllers that had this problem have a common base class with a strong delegate outlet. Voilá.

Comment: @MikeLischke Heh-- I know that feeling.  I do encourage you to figure out the Allocations instrument.  Many a performance woe has been solved by minimizing allocation rates, for example, and it is a great tool.